# Compare first column in two files, if match: update last column variable, else: append line to second file

Tags: awk, text-processing

I want to take col1 of file1 and if there is a match in col1 of file2, update the "date updated" in the last column. If there is no match, I want to append the entire line of file1 to file2 and append a "date updated" value to that line as well.

I am currently using `awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] > 0' file2 file1` for a baseline comparison, but that wrongly prints the whole line IF there is a match and I also cannot figure out how to add another condition for updating the date column. I am also trying to do this in a shell script.

file 1

```
userName | cpu% | command | date created

   user1, 101.6, plasma-de+, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
   user2, 100.0, plasma-de+, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
   user3, 102.0, plasma-de+, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
```

file 2

```
userName | cpu% | command | date created | date updated

    user1, 101.6, plasma-de+, Mon Aug  5 06:35:39 MDT 2019,    Mon Aug  5 06:35:39 MDT 2019 
    user2, 100.0, plasma-de+, Mon Aug  5 06:35:39 MDT 2019,    Mon Aug  5 06:35:39 MDT 2019
```

file 2 after command is run

```
userName | cpu% | command | date created | date updated

    user1, 101.6, plasma-de+, Mon Aug  5 06:35:39 MDT 2019,    Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
    user2, 100.0, plasma-de+, Mon Aug  5 06:35:39 MDT 2019,    Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
    user3, 102.0, plasma-de+, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019,    Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
```

Comment: How are your columns delimited? With tabs?

Comment: @Shawn Just spaces. The information was initially taken from calling "top"

Comment: That must make dealing with the timestamp strings fun then. It certainly complicates an answer when you don't add one column, but 6.

Comment: @Shawn How do I get around that? Top spits out the first 3 columns and I manually append the date created value after that.

Comment: If you start with just the first three columns, it's easy to use sed or something to replace those spaces with tabs, commas, or some other field separator and keep using it when adding columns.

Comment: @Shawn Ah that was easy enough. Updated my post, columns are now seperated with a comma as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

One non-awk way that assumes your files are sorted:

```
$ (join -t, -j1 -o 0,2.2,2.3,2.4,1.4 file1 file2; \
   join -t, -j1 -v1 -o 0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.4 file1 file2)
user1, 101.6, plasma-de+, Mon Aug  5 06:35:39 MDT 2019, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
user2, 100.0, plasma-de+, Mon Aug  5 06:35:39 MDT 2019, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
user3, 102.0, plasma-de+, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
```

or using awk without that restriction:

```
$awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
      NR == FNR { a[$1] = $0; b[$1] = $4; next }
      $1 in a { $5 = b[$1]; delete a[$1]; print }
      END { for (u in a) print a[u], b[u] }' file1 file2
user1, 101.6, plasma-de+, Mon Aug  5 06:35:39 MDT 2019, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
user2, 100.0, plasma-de+, Mon Aug  5 06:35:39 MDT 2019, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
user3, 102.0, plasma-de+, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019, Thu Aug  8 09:30:17 MDT 2019
```

Comment: Using that command isn't giving me the results I need. It just returns file 1.